# How do I access $scope variables in Angular 1 after using keyword this?

Tags: angularjs, scope, this, angularjs-ng-repeat

I think I'm having a problem with scope in Angular. I'm trying to iterate through an array of images that I get back from a request using ng-repeat, but I can't seem to access a variable that will let me do it. here's my index.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="myImage in picData">
<img ng-src="{{getImagePath(myImage)}}"/>
</div>
```

And here's my controller:

```
angular.module('ChooseForMe',['ngFileUpload']) // naming the module
.controller('inputController', ['Upload', '$window', '$scope','$http', function(Upload, $window, $scope, $http){ // defining the controller, inject $scope and $http

    $scope.entry;
    $scope.username = 'Anonymous';
    $scope.password;

    var temporary;
    $scope.picData = []
    $scope.textData = ['hey'];
    var newData = $scope.newData;
    $scope.pictures = [];
    $scope.object = {};
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.temp = [];

    $scope.getImagePath = function(imageName) {
        console.log('pathin: ',"/uploads/" + imageName )
    return "/uploads/" + imageName;};   

var vm = this;
    vm.submit = function(){
        if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.file) { //check if from is valid
        vm.upload(vm.file); //call upload function
        }
    }

    vm.upload = function (file) {
        console.log("me file: ", file);
        var newFile = file;

        Upload.upload({
            url: 'http://localhost:8672/upload', //webAPI exposed to upload the file
            data:{file:file} //pass file as data, should be user ng-model
        }).then(function (resp) { //upload function returns a promise
            if(resp.data.error_code === 0){ //validate success
                $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ');
                    $http({
                    'method': 'GET',
                    'url': '/upload',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                   console.log('This is the Picture response data: ', response.data);
                   $scope.picData = response.data;
                   console.log('PICS!!!!!!!!!!',$scope.picData)
                   temp = $scope.picData;
                   vm.picData = temp;
                   console.log("TEMP!", temp, 'vm.picData', vm.picData);
                   console.log("in client success response, sending this to local $scope.data: ", $scope.data, "scope.temp: ", $scope.temp);
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log('uh oh, we got an error in the Get response: ', response);
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });
    //             $scope.picData.push(newFile.name)
                // console.log('after image upload picData', $scope.picData, "and textData", $scope.textData);
            } else {
                $window.alert('an error occured');
            }
        }, function (resp) { //catch error
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            $window.alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        }, function (evt) { 
            console.log(evt);
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
            vm.progress = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '; // capture upload progress
        });
    };
```

So, I've tried to save the array of picture names in $scope.picData and also in var temporary. But when I try to access it with ng-repeat, it doesn't work. it comes back empty when I console log $scope.picData. var temporary has all the data, but I can't access it with ng-repeat. Is this a scope issue?

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Controller as Syntax

```
<div ng-controller="inputController as vm">
<div ng-repeat="myImage in vm.picData">
<img ng-src="{{vm.getImagePath(myImage)}}"/>
</div>
```

Also change your getImagePath and othe scope variables using vm.

```
vm.getImagePath = function(imageName) {
    console.log('pathin: ',"/uploads/" + imageName )
    return "/uploads/" + imageName;};  
    var vm = this;
    vm.submit = function(){
        if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.file) { //check if from is valid
        vm.upload(vm.file); //call upload function
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan thanks for the effort, I tried your solutions, but It's still not working. None of the images are displaying. I have a full vm.picData array but ng-repeat is not iterating through them and displaying them. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JonathanZungre i need to see your code. add me on skype : sajee4ever